# Transform data on mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I have collection that has an array field and string date field. How do i transform my mongo data that looks like:

```
{"d" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], "date" : "21-10-2020" }
```

to

```
{"21-10-2020" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

using query?

Is there a way to do this transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$arrayToObject` convert array format of k(key) and v(value) and it will convert to object
- `$replaceWith` replace object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: [
        [{ k: "$date", v: "$d" }]
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S8EhxC3C7D6)

Comment: you can use $replaceRoot as well,